# How to hide the dropdown button of the excel table while printing in Visio Professional 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-visio-2016

I am inserting an [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK7o8.jpg) through an object (Excel sheet) in a visio and trying to make a diagram using a table. While [printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38qZY.jpg) the visio drawing i am getting the dropdown button of the table with unexpected format of the table, like the fonts are getting messy. I want to hide the dropdown button after i print and maintain the format of the table in the sense we normally format the table in excel with colors and proper fonts and headings but not able to achieve the desired result in visio. 
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I do not use Visio so cannot give a definitive answer to most of your issues.

The filter buttons though, can be made to go away using the Excel Ribbon command `Table Design` and then unselecting (unchecking) the `Fileter Button` checkbox in the `Table Styles Options` submenu. For quick finding, that is the submenu just to the left of the very noticeable `Table Styles` submenu (which is the rightmost one, with all the colorfully banded options).

In general, my experience with inserting/embedding material from other programs is that fonts do not usually become "messy" unless the embedding area is smaller than the "natural" size of the embedded material. In other words, if the material prints in a 4" x 7" block when printed from Excel with no resizing applied IN EXCEL, and you are embedding it into a, say, 3" x 6" block in Visio, the odds are the fonts will be "resized", sort of, the way Excel does when Zooming... in short, nicely for some Zooms, badly for others with "badly" becomeing worse as the size gets smaller. My take is it is not really resizing what is in the view, for instance, going from a 12pt font to a 9pt font for a 75% Zoom and THEN applying anti-aliasing and so on, but rather applying any niceties like anti-aliasing, THEN changing the processssed items' size so nothing dresses it up after reduction.

Perhaps give embedding the Table in its natural size a whirl:  see if fonts get messy, and if they do, well, that's not it. But if they then look fine, consider the above. My best shot at a fix, if that happens, would be to resize in Excel where you can make everything nice, then Excel and Windows apply their niceties, and you get a fully functional, natural item, taking full advantage of the niceties, inserted/embedded in Visio.

As to the other failures, you give even less detail about just how they are failing to come over so I shall not hazard even a guess at them.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this and get back to you on the update.